# React-Native can't access second level from firestore response

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have a detail screen that retrieves a document with this structure:

```
Object {
  "category": Object {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Concerts",
  },
  "date": Object {
    "end": Object {
      "nanoseconds": 543000000,
      "seconds": 1660705200,
    },
    "start": Object {
      "nanoseconds": 49000000,
      "seconds": 1660698000,
    },
  },
  "title": "Gravity Funk",
}
```

If I display "title" it works, but I cannot access something like "category.name", in the list that comes before this screen in the navigation stack I solve it by calling renderItem function from Flatlist but I don't know how to do it here and I can't find any documentation for this doc() method from Firestore. Here's the code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {...};
  
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore(app);


const EventScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {

    let category;
    const eventId = route.params.eventId;
    const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
    const getEvent = async (dbx) => {
        let isMounted = true;
        const eventDoc = doc(dbx, 'events', eventId);
        const eventSnapshot = await getDoc(eventDoc);
        const fetchedEvent = eventSnapshot.data();
        setEvent(fetchedEvent);
        return fetchedEvent;
    }    

    useEffect(  
        () => {
            getEvent(db);
        }
    ,[])


    return ( 
        <View>
            <Text>{event.title}</Text>
            <Text>{event.category.name}</Text>
        </View>
    )

}
```

And here's the error message I'm getting:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.category.name')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by declaring a specific object for each second-level item like this:

```
const eventId = route.params.eventId;
const [eventCategory, setEventCategory] = useState({});
const [event, setEvent] = useState({});
const [eventDate, setEventDate] = useState({});
```

And inside the getEvent function I had to specifically call the item.

```
const eventDoc = doc(dbx, 'events', eventId);
const eventSnapshot = await getDoc(eventDoc);
const fetchedEvent = eventSnapshot.data();
setEvent(fetchedEvent);
setEventCategory (fetchedEvent.category);
setEventDate (()=>({
  start: fetchedEvent.date.start.toDate().toString(),
  end: fetchedEvent.date.end.toDate().toString()
}));
```

Notice how I had to call a function for setEventDate as it is a timestamp from firestore. I don't know if this is the correct way to do it but it works.